# prime number finder, it's in python

Tags: python

```
# this program will test numbers and check if they are prime numbers or even numbers

num = eval(input('Enter a number: '))#generating user input
for i in range(num):
    x = 2
    if num % 2 == 0: #test for even numbers
        print(num, x, 'is even')
    else:
        while num % x != 0:#the idea here is to enter a loop and test the numbers against x=2, x +=1... to check if they are divisible
            x += 1         #by x
            break
        if num % x == 0:    #x is however either 2 or 3. it never advances to four and numbers like 25 become prime numbers
            print(num,x, 'is odd')
        else:
            print(num,x, 'is prime')
    num -=1
```

There's a logical flaw in the code I just can't figure out where it is

Comment: Use `int()` not `eval()`!

Comment: Yeah this is homework

Comment: So many issues. What is the `for` loop for - you never use `i` anywhere? Note that `range()` starts at 0 unless you specify otherwise. If num is not divisible by 2, it will not be divisible by any other even number, so you could use `x += 2` to skip all even nums. `while num % x != 0` is the same as `while num % x`.

Comment: I used int() but it didn't work

Comment: [You really need to know how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)! This is critical to your success, and is actually the _reason_ for this homework. That is, coding homework is not really about getting correct behaviour, but finding out how to solve the problems you encounter while trying to get the correct behaviour.

Comment: if you want extra credit you should look into implementing the sieve of eranthoses

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
num = eval(input('Enter a number: '))
```

To:

```
num = input('Enter a number: ')
if num.is_digit(): #evaluate if is a number
    num = int(num)
else:
    #broke code logic
    num = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test for primality much faster with:

```
num > 1 and all(num % i for i in xrange(2, sqrt(num)))
```

In your code:

```
    num = int(input('Enter a number: ')) 
    for i in range(num): 
        x = 2 
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print(num, x, 'is even') 
        else: 
            if num > 1 and all(num % i for i in xrange(2, sqrt(num))):
                print(num,x,'is prime')
            else: print(num,x,"is odd")
        num -=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is in this chunk:

```
while num % x != 0:
    x += 1
    break
```

... you have an unconditional `break`, meaning the loop will never run more than once. Compare

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 4:
        return n in {2, 3}
    elif not n % 2:
        # even
        return False
    else:
        return all(n % div for div in range(3, int(n ** 0.5 + 1.), 2))
```

then your program looks like

```
def main():
    print("Show all primes up to what number?")
    upto = int(input(": "))
    for n in range(2, upto + 1):
        if is_prime(n):
            print("{} is prime".format(n))
        else:
            print("{} is {}".format(n, ["even", "odd"][n % 2]))
main()
```